# EMGU error when trying to install Emgu.CV.runtime.windows VS 2019 winforms, framework 4.8

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, emgucv

I am trying to install EMGU using Nuget.  I am using **Framework 4.8. WinForms**. I'm able to install Emgu.CV but when I try installing Emgu.CV.runtime.windows I get an error saying:

*"Could not install package 'Emgu.runtime.windows.msvc.rt.x64 19.28.29336'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

One solution on stackoverflow ([Emgu error when trying to install emgu.CV.runtime.windows in VC# 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986063/emgu-error-when-trying-to-install-emgu-cv-runtime-windows-in-vc-2017)) says that "the solution is migrating from package.config to package references" but it didn't work in my case. When I changed migrating I get an error when installing Emgu.CV too. The error is  *"Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet'."*

After these I tried manually installing Emgu.runtime and copying dll files but I got a problem related to cvextern.dll. It says that the file is not accessible. I tried registering it rgsvr32 it didn't work. So working manually didn't help either.

How am I supposed to install EMGU.

Comment: Uninstall everything related to Emgu.cv. Set the Platform Target to `AnyCPU`. Rebuild the solution. Close Visual Studio. Delete everything in `[Project]\obj`. Install [OpenCV 4.5.2 for Windows](https://opencv.org/releases/). Open up NuGet Package Manager, find `Emgu.cv 4.5.1` and `Emgu.cv.runtime.windows 4.5.1` and install both packages using `PackageReference` as the management format. Check Visual Studio's config, make sure that the default  `Package Management` is set to `PackageReference` and `Allow format selection on first package install` is ticked.

Comment: See whether both `Emgu.CV.Platform.NetFramework.dll` and `Emgu.CV.Platform.NetStandard.dll` are added to the output folders (`Debug`/`Release`) of your Solution. All other assemblies are stored in the `x86` and `x64` folders. -- Now, if something goes wrong for some weird reason, build a new Solution and start over.

Comment: Thank you.I still get an error when I select PackageReference and try installing Emgu.CV.  I get this error: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\'.

Comment: There's a new version of Emgu.CV, v. 4.5.2, which is based on OpenCV 4.5.2 (that you need to download and install beforehand). Note that Emgu.CV uses .Net Standard, there's just a simple wrapper for .Net Framework. -- Install Emgu.CV 4.5.2 first, then Emgu.CV.runtime.windows 4.5.2. Also add the Emgu.CV.UI package (last).  After the installation, you must see the Packages **blue icons** in the Project's References and the standard icon of `Emgu.CV.Platform.NetFramework`. -- Do this in a new Solution. Target **AnyCPU** and remove the default `Prefer 32-bit` check.

Comment: The new versions don't install the x86 / x64 components in the Projects output folders (Debug/Release) anymore. -- See that you have updated your Visual Studio installation and .Net Standard is functional.

Answer (score 0):

.netFramework version is not compatible with the package that you are trying to install.

> 1-Uninstall the packages completely from your project. 2-downgrade
> your project's .netFramework version from Properties of the project
> 3-Reinstall the packages.

Comment: Yes, it's compatible. Also, `Emgu.runtime.windows.msvc.rt.x64` has no dependencies. The problem is somewhere else (probably some components missing). I know because I use .Net Framework 4.8 with Emgu.CV.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version (2023), you must specify the Target as x64 (or, x86). Also, need to do changes in Tools->Options (from Config to Reference, etc). Details are clearly explained here:
https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Targeting_.Net_Framework